Acquire token silent using MSAL v1 not working in my ANGULAR JS application
I am working on ANGULAR JS application with MSAL v1, how can i achieve to get token using acquire token silent ,in my enterprise system third party cookies are blocked in chrome
i tried using MSAL v2 but i was getting error in my ANGULAR JS application as it was not supporting as MSAL v2 files are not compatible with ANGULAR JS

I tried the AngularJS code below to get the access token from Azure AD. You can check the complete code in this GitHub repository.
auth.service.ts :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PublicClientApplication, AuthError, AuthenticationResult, SilentRequest } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './auth-config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private app: PublicClientApplication;
  private isMsalInitialized: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.app = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    this.initializeMsal();
  }
  private async initializeMsal(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.app.initialize();
      await this.app.handleRedirectPromise();
      this.isMsalInitialized = true; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('MSAL initialization error:', error);
    }
  }
  async login(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }
    try {
      const loginResponse = await this.app.loginPopup({
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
      });
      console.log('Login successful', loginResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error.errorMessage);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error during login:', error);
      }
    }
  }
  async logout(): Promise<void> {
    this.app.logout();
  }
  async acquireTokenSilent(scopes: string[]): Promise<AuthenticationResult> {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }
    try {
      const accounts = this.app.getAllAccounts();
      if (accounts.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('No accounts found. User needs to be signed in.');
      }

      const silentRequest: SilentRequest = {
        scopes: scopes,
        account: accounts[0]
      };
      const response = await this.app.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
      console.log('Token acquired silently', response);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) {
        console.error('Silent token acquisition error:', error.errorMessage);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error during silent token acquisition:', error);
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

sso.component.ts :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sso',
  templateUrl: './sso.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sso.component.css'],
})
export class SsoComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  login(): void {
    this.authService.login();
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
  async getToken() {
    try {
      const tokenResponse = await this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read']);
      console.log('Access Token:', tokenResponse.accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error acquiring token silently:', error);
    }
  }
}

sso.component.html :
<h1>Single Sign-On with Microsoft Azure AD</h1>
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
<button (click)="getToken()">Get Token</button>

I added the following URL as a redirect URI in Azure AD, configuring it as a single-page application, as shown below.
http://localhost:4200/


Output :
I got the below page in the browser and received the access token after clicking on Get Token and logging in, as shown.


I am using msal v1 , which uses Useragentapplication! Any suggestions on how to get token using userAgentapplication

@BhumikaGC To use UserAgentApplication with MSAL v1, you can use the acquireTokenSilent and loginPopup methods directly from UserAgentApplication for token retrieval.
